# What is the highest level of equipment/weapons found in the game?

Tags: rebel-galaxy

Right now I have various weapons/shields/boosters/etc. on my ship ranging from Mk 2 to Mk 5. Looking at the sector map, I've been through *maybe* 1/2 of the different systems.

By the end of the game, what is the highest level of "stuff" I will be able to buy? Mk 5? Mk 7? Mk 10+?
Is this limit the same for everything in the game, or do some things 'top off' at a higher level than others?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the wiki, it depends on the type of weapon. The highest weapon of any type is a Mk 6. Here are some links to specific weapon types:

- [Broadsides](http://rebelgalaxy.gamepedia.com/Category:Broadsides)
- [Secondaries](http://rebelgalaxy.gamepedia.com/Category:Secondary_Weapon)
- [Turrets](http://rebelgalaxy.gamepedia.com/Category:Turret)

General equipment information can be found on the [equipment wiki page](http://rebelgalaxy.gamepedia.com/Category:Equipment).